# How to reduce the execution time?

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0, tfs

Code:

```
testItemList = testResults.Select(item => project.Store.GetWorkItem(item.TargetId)).ToList();
```

testItemList is **(local variable) List testItemList**

testResults is **(local variable) WorkItemLinkInfo[] testResults**

Totally, 610 work items are present. How to reduce the execution time? As of now, it takes 20 seconds to execute this line of code.
How to fine tune the above code, so that to reduce the execution time?

Comment: 610 is very very small. Are these being loaded from a database? Perhaps you have an N+1 problem and those 610 iterations are 610 queries.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, No, The items are loaded from the TFS.

Comment: It will probaly run a lot fast without the `ToList()`. But that's just moving the costs around.

Comment: what do you ger in testItemList when you debug? Do you see number of queries? i think @SimonWhitehead is right. It seems like you have a N+1 problem

Comment: @Rohan, If it is N+1 problem, whether any solution is there to fine tune the code.

Comment: Can you paste `project.Store.GetWorkItem(item.TargetId)`? These calls are probably expensive.

Comment: you are loading from cloud or local?

Comment: @jhyap, From local, I am loading.

Comment: Show us `GetWorkItem` please. If it is part of an external API.. at least explain what it does.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://clipperhouse.com/2009/10/12/solving-the-n1-problem-in-linq-to-sql-using-projection/). **If** its a n+1 problem you just need to create a class that would minimize the query.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, the `GetWorkItem` is from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`

Comment: Why do you need to fetch complete 610 work items ? You can use Query and search on all work item fields. Please describe better what are you tring to do.

Comment: @AntonioBakula, i am trying to check if it is a linked `if (query.IsLinkQuery)` query and for this, I am working around.

Comment: @JohnStephen sorry, I don't understand. IsLinkQuery is property of Query not work item list. Are you tryng to get test results ? If so please update your question.

Comment: @AntonioBakula, I am getting `testItemList` which has `count` of `610 work items`. But the issue is it takes some `20 to 21` seconds to execute. `var testResults = query.RunLinkQuery();` is used to get the `testResults`

Comment: 1)`item.TargetId` is in `sorted order` or `un-sorted order`?

2)Total how many items inside `testResults`?

Comment: @jhyap, `item.TargetId` is in unsorted order and totally `610` items are present inside testResults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Query query = new Query(project.Store, "Select [Title] From WorkItems", testResults.Select(item => item.TargetId).ToArray());
var car = query.BeginQuery();
//Do something else while awaiting server response...
testItemList = query.EndQuery(car);
```

Your code does 610 total round trips to the server, and downloads every field of each workitem. This code does a single round trip, and downloads only the Title field.

Note that you will still be able to access every field of each workitem in testitemlist, but each access to a field not included in the original query string will entail another round trip.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx

Comment: How to convert workitemcollection to dictionary ? I am having this code

`var testItemMapQuery = testItemList.ToDictionary(w => w, createItemFromQuery);`

Comment: `testItemList.Cast<WorkItem>.ToDictionary(w => w.id, w => w);`?

Comment: In `Cast<WorkItem>`, the error message is displaying as `System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable) is a method which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: I use the following code to convert from `workitemcollection` to `list<WorkItem>`..`testItemCollectionList = (from WorkItem mItem in testItemCollection select mItem).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

I will take a guess: Store is a WorkItemStore?
What is testResults?

Your linq statement will result in a for loop. Making a new query for each ID. You could possibly speed up the result by using a batch query.
Maybe WorkItemStore.Query(id[], wiql) can speed up. Giving in a list of ids.
You would get a WorkItemCollection then. The "wiql" is query language to specify the fields you want.
Sorry for the short answer. I don't have a TFS at hand to give it a try and post a tested code snippet.